# Add variable to window

Tags: typescript

I`ve added

window.d.ts file with next content
as proposed by many answers here

```
interface Window {
    gameManager?: any;
}
```

but still getting `Property 'gameManager' does not exist on type 'Window'`

Do you have any idea how to simply add variable to window object without so much pain?

Comment: You might be writing your code inside a module and not in the global scope.  If so, you need to use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation).  Try wrapping your above interface in `declare global { ... }` and see if it fixes your issue

Comment: i`ve tried this, this adds "Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations." error, and if i add something like "export {}" after declare global i still got "Property 'gameManager' does not exist on type 'Window'"

Comment: Move the `declare global {}` out of any nested blocks, maybe?    (If you want a better chance of having your problem solved you should try to make this into a [mcve].  We don't have access to your system, so all I can do is make guesses unless you provide enough details for the issue to be reproduced.)

Comment: Well, you can check in my question, that this only file content, no nested blocks

Comment: While you wait for someone to come along who knows how to read questions, I would suggest you review the guidelines about [how to ask a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what constitutes a [mcve].  Good luck!

Answer (score 14):

So, if you do, as often recommended:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    CONFIG: any
  }
}
```

then you will get the TS2669 error: *"Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations."*

This is confusing, but the answer apparently is to wrap it in an external module declaration:

```js
declare module 'my-config' {
  global {
    interface Window {
      CONFIG: any
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you do not need to import `my-config` anywhere, and the name of that take module seems irrelevant. `window.CONFIG` will simply be available globally.